# Winsock error when running SQL Server Stored Proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, winsock

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is trying to read emails from an IMAP server (I am using mail.dll from [www.limilabs.com](http://www.limilabs.com)).
The SP works fine on my local computer/db, and the code also runs fine when run from a console application on my remote server. When I try to run it from SQL Server however I get a Winsock error message:

```
   Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetEmails, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetEmails": 
Limilabs.Client.ServerException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Limilabs.Client.ClientBase.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Boolean useSSL)
Limilabs.Client.ServerException: 
   at Limilabs.Client.ClientBase.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Boolean useSSL)
   at StoredProcedures.GetEmails()
```

I suspect it is something to do with permissions (??) but it is beyond my knowledge of SQL Server.
Anyone have some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: The stack clearly shows that this is a DNS issue. Maybe an IPv4/6 confusion?

Comment: Not sure that would explain why I don't get the error when running the code outside SQL Server?

Comment: I don't know the answer but a procedure reading IMAP mails sounds like a bad architecture. Put that code into the app. Seems to mostly have disadvantages putting it into the database.

Comment: Actually the code runs in an external assembly and (should) just return data to SQL Server